# Comparisons of Conditional Expectations

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Suppose $X_1,X_2,...,X_m$ are $m$ independent random variables. Let $L(k)$ be the $k$ largest random variables among them. Do we always have $$E[X_i\mid X_i \in L(k)]\ge E[X_i\mid X_i \not \in L(k)]?$$

Comment: Why do you think this is false?

Comment: I believe it is true, but I can prove it only for the i.i.d. case.

Comment: Fanqi, I am unsure if you are using the basic definition of conditional expectation or the sigma-algebra definition, but since the event $\{X_i \in L(k)\}$ has positive measure, both definitions reduce to the classic/basic one and the exercise is quite easy and the answer below applies.

Comment: @WillM. What is the point of your comment? It comes across as trivializing OP's question, which is not needed at best and rude at worst.

Comment: @MikeEarnest con can it possibly be trivialising or be construed as rude? When I learned conditional expectation, I was unable to "click" that the basic definition coincided with the sigma-algebra one until far later in my doctorate (i.e. for 5 years or so I thought the two of them as parallel without much connection beyond intuition). So, maybe OP has a similar difficulty. Anyway, I cannot possibly understand how my comment is either rude or trivialising, maybe you are projecting your own insecurities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Y$ denote the $k^\text{th}$ largest value among all of the variables except for $X_i$. Then $E[X_i\mid X_i\in L(k)]=E[X_i\mid X_i\ge Y]$, where $X_i$ and $Y$ are independent. Therefore, your question is equivalent to:

> If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, is $E[X\mid X\ge Y]\ge E[X\mid X<Y]$?

Obviously, this is true when $Y$ is deterministically equal to the real number $y$, since $E[X\mid X\ge y]\ge y\ge E[X\mid X<y]$. Therefore, it is true when you average over $y$ according to the distribution of $Y$.

To add some more detail, letting $f(y)$ be the pdf of $Y$, then
$$
E[X\mid X\ge Y]=\int E[X\mid X\ge y]f(y)\,dy\ge \int E[X\mid X<y]f(y)\,dy = E[X\mid X<Y]
$$

Comment: If $Y$ is the $k$th-largest largest one other than $X_i,$ then the event that $X_i$ is one of the $k$ largest ones is the event that $X_i>Y$ (in which case $Y$ is the $(k+1)$th-largest), not $X_i\ge Y. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Let $k=2,i=1$, and consider $(X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4)=(2,1,2,3)$. Here, $X_1$ is not greater than the second largest of $\{X_2,X_3,X_4\}$, so according to your comment, the event that $X_1$ is one of the largest two values has not occurred. I say this event has occurred, since $X_1=2$, and the set of two largest values is $\{1,2\}$.